# shuffling data change OPTICS outlier results

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, outliers

I am trying to use sklearn.cluster.OPTICS to identify outliers, but found an issue:

I use 2 examples with exactly the same data but different orders. They give different results:

1. 1st example
   ////////////////////////////////////////////
   from sklearn.cluster import OPTICS
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   X = np.array([[1], [2], [3],[1],[8], [8], [7],
   [100]
   ])

clust  = OPTICS(min_samples=3, metric='euclidean',).fit(X)
clust.labels_
////////////////////////////////////////////
output: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

2. 2nd example
   ////////////////////////////////////////////
   from sklearn.cluster import OPTICS
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   X = np.array([[1], [2], [3],[8], [8], [7],
   [100],[1]
   ])

clust  = OPTICS(min_samples=3, metric='euclidean',).fit(X)
clust.labels_
////////////////////////////////////////////
output:
array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1, -1,  0])

We can see X has the same data but different orders. The 2nd output is supposed to be correct as [100] should be an outlier.  But oddly, if we change the order of the data, the model gave wrong results.

Can anyone help?

thanks

Ya